# Is there a faster way to compare data between dynamic arrays in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have the below code working successfully, however it has to run on two arrays of 130k+ rows each. Current run time on the full data set is around 24 minutes and having added a count at one point, it is looping 9.8 billion times.

I have read through articles on using Match, Vlookup and they all seem to suggest that an iterative loop (as I have used) is the fastest method, however I have been unable to understand how to get the other methods to work with dynamic arrays and hence test appropriately.

Is anyone able to tell me if there is a faster way to complete this activity, and if so, demonstrate how?

```
Sub TESTVLOOKUPARRAY()
    Dim PSORG1() As Variant
    Dim PSORG1Tot As Variant
    Dim PSORG1RT As Variant
    Dim PSORG2() As Variant
    Dim PSORG2Tot As Variant
    Dim PSORG2RT As Variant

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    PSORG2RT = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    PSORG2Tot = "A1:B" & PSORG2RT
    PSORG2 = Range(PSORG2Tot) ' PSORG2 is now an allocated array

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    PSORG1RT = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    PSORG1Tot = "A1:B" & PSORG1RT
    PSORG1 = Range(PSORG1Tot) ' PSORG1 is now an allocated array

    a = 2 ' to increment ORG values in PSORG1

    Do
        Finish = "No"
        b = 1 ' to increment ORG values in PSORG2
        Do
            If PSORG1(a, 1) = PSORG2(b, 1) Then
                PSORG1(a, 2) = PSORG2(b, 2)
                Finish = "True"
            ElseIf b = PSORG2RT Then
                PSORG1(a, 2) = "NULL"
                Finish = "True"
            End If
            b = b + 1
        Loop Until Finish = "True"
        a = a + 1
    Loop Until a = PSORG1RT + 1

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Set Destination = Range("A1")
    Destination.Resize(UBound(PSORG1, 1), UBound(PSORG1, 2)).Value = PSORG1

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd use an ArrayList instead as it has a `.Exists()` method for fast comparison.

Comment: Be sure to let us know who the winner was (on your data). :P

Comment: Since your code is functioning as expected, just slower than you'd like, this would be a much better fit on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concur with the Scripting.Dictionary method.

> This procedure makes use of a Scripting.Dictionsry. You need to go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Sub TESTVLOOKUPARRAY()
    Dim PSORG1 As Variant, PSORG2 As Variant
    Dim a As Long, b As Long
    Dim dPSORG2 As New Scripting.dictionary

    dPSORG2.CompareMode = TextCompare

    Debug.Print Timer

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        PSORG2 = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(a, 2).Value2 ' PSORG2 is now an allocated array
        For b = LBound(PSORG2, 1) To UBound(PSORG2, 1)
            dPSORG2.Item(PSORG2(b, 1)) = PSORG2(b, 2)
        Next b
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        PSORG1 = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(a, 2).Value2 ' PSORG1 is now an allocated array
    End With

    Debug.Print dPSORG2.Count
    Debug.Print LBound(PSORG2, 1) & ":" & UBound(PSORG2, 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(PSORG2, 2) & ":" & UBound(PSORG2, 2)
    Debug.Print LBound(PSORG1, 1) & ":" & UBound(PSORG1, 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(PSORG1, 2) & ":" & UBound(PSORG1, 2)

    For b = LBound(PSORG1, 1) To UBound(PSORG1, 1)
        If dPSORG2.Exists(PSORG1(b, 1)) Then
            PSORG1(b, 2) = dPSORG2.Item(PSORG1(b, 1))
        Else
            PSORG1(b, 2) = "NULL"
        End If
    Next b


    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(PSORG1, 1), UBound(PSORG1, 2)) = PSORG1
    End With

    Debug.Print Timer

End Sub
```

> FWIW, my sample data of 110K rows on Sheet1 and 95K rows in Sheet2 ran in 20 minutes, 40 seconds with your original code. The above took 1.72 seconds on the same data.

Comment: So, I went with this option, it seemed to make most sense and in short tests it was considerably faster.
I then went to modify this for the live data sets, where I am trying to pull three columns of data through into the original data set.
For one column of data it was pulling through in around 7-8 minutes. However, to pull through multiple columns, I couldn't find a way to get this to work without creating another loop or defining multiple dictionaries. This tripled the overhead and resulted in a worse time to run than the original. Wish I understood it more :(

Comment: The logic path here seems convoluted, this could really use inline comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think using Dictionaries would make the code faster.

Below is the code doing the same task but it uses Dictionary object.
On my computer it is about 100x faster than your own code (tested on two worksheets with 5K rows each, for bigger data sets the gain should be even better).

```
Public Function TestVLookupArray2()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim destination As Excel.Range


    'Load values from Sheet1 into Dictionary.
    Set dict = getDataFromSheetAsDictionary(Sheets("Sheet1"))

    result = getDataFromSheet(Sheets("Sheet2"))

    For i = LBound(result, 1) To UBound(result, 1)

        With dict
            If .exists(result(i, 1)) Then
                result(i, 2) = .Item(result(i, 1))
            Else
                result(i, 2) = "NULL"
            End If
        End With

    Next i

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set destination = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2)))
        destination = result
    End With

End Function


Private Function getDataFromSheet(wks As Excel.Worksheet) As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With wks
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        getDataFromSheet = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 2))
    End With

End Function


Private Function getDataFromSheetAsDictionary(wks As Excel.Worksheet) As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim key As String
    Dim value As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant

    Set getDataFromSheetAsDictionary = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    arr = getDataFromSheet(wks)

    With getDataFromSheetAsDictionary
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

            If Not .exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                Call .Add(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2))
            End If

        Next i
    End With

End Function
```

Note that this code consists of 3 separate functions, you need to include all of them.

Here is the article introducing to Dictionaries: http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html

If you have any questions to this code, let me know in comments.

Comment: How are you returning the values back into Sheet2 from the function(s)?

Comment: @Jeeped `destination = result`

Comment: I guess I would have just kept that one as a sub since it returns no value.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a `for next` loop, as a pose to the `do` loop used by yourself.

```
Sub speed_up2()
    Dim PSORG1() As Variant, PSORG2() As Variant
    Dim PSORG1Tot As Range, PSORG2Tot As Range, Destination As Range
    Dim PSORG1RT As Long, PSORG2RT As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws_1 As Worksheet, ws_2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Byte, j As Byte

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws_2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    with ws_1
        PSORG2RT = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Get last row
        Set PSORG2Tot = .Range("A1:B" & PSORG2RT)
        PSORG2 = PSORG2Tot ' PSORG2 is now an allocated array
    End With

    With ws_2
        PSORG1RT = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set PSORG1Tot = .Range("A1:B" & PSORG1RT)
        PSORG1 = PSORG1Tot ' PSORG1 is now an allocated array
    End With

    For i = 1 To UBound(PSORG1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(PSORG2)
            PSORG1(i, 2) = "NULL"
            If PSORG1(i, 1) = PSORG2(j, 1) Then
                PSORG1(i, 2) = PSORG2(j, 2)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Set Destination = ws_2.Range("A1")
    Destination.Resize(UBound(PSORG1, 1), UBound(PSORG1, 2)).Value = PSORG1
End Sub
```

Please see [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/797078-next-vs-do-loop-winner) for a speedtest which was performed between the `for next` loop and the `do` loop.

As specified in the article, the `for next` loop is performing the calculation of the next iteration for you, whereas with the `do` loop you are having to increment the iteration yourself each time. This can save a large amount of time.

I've also amended the method of getting the last row, which is used to create the range. This is my personal preference; it may also be safer to use than `Application.COUNTA`.

Comment: If you assign `PSORG2(i, 2) = "NULL"` before entering the `For j = 1 To UBound(PSORG2)` it will be overwritten (and exited) if found otherwise it will stay the same. Might be marginally faster than continually checking if you have reached the end of the loop.

Comment: That's true. Good tip @Jeeped. I've amended the code. Thanks!